# Which it is the best way to fill a dropdowlist in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, model

Which it is the best way in which you do not have to repeat the code in the Get and Post method to populate a DropDownList

That in view of creating and editing , I need to deploy some dropdowlist of related tables and do not want to be repeating viewbag in the GET and POST methods

Example :

A view where employees are recognized at an apartment, there is a Department employee relationship with.

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; } 

    [DisplayName("Employee Name")]
    [Required]
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Department Id")]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Department Name")]
    [Required]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

And the controller method

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName");
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Employees.Add(employee);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName", employee.DepartmentId);
    return View(employee);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move it to a method and call it in both the places. I recommend using a strongly typed view model for transferring data between your action method and view ,instead of using dynamic stuff like ViewBag and ViewData.

```
public class CreateUserVM
{
  public int UserId {set;get;}
  public string Name {set;get;}
  public List<SelectListItem> Departments {set;get;}
  public int SelectedDept {set;get;}

  public CreateUserVM()
  {
    this.Departments = new List<SelectListItem>();
  }

}
```

And in the GET action,

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var vm = new CreateUserVM(); 
    vm.Departments = GetDeperatements();
    return View(vm);
}

private List<SelectListItem> GetDeperatements()
{
   return db.Departments.Select(s=> new SelectListItem { 
                                    Value=DepartmentId.ToString(),
                                    Text = "DepartmentName"
                               }).ToList();
}
```

Your view is bound to the `CreateUserVM` view model

```
@model YourNamespaceHere.CreateUserVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.DropdownListFor(s=>s.SelectedDept,Model.Departments,"Select on")
  @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Name)
  @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.UserId)
  <input type="submit" />
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateUserVM model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        //Map the view model to entity

        var emp = new Employee();
        emp.Name = model.Name;
        emp.DepartmentId = model.SelectedDept;

        db.Employees.Add(emp);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }    
    employee.Departments = GetDeperatements();
    return View(employee);
}
```

For Your edit screen, You can use the same code as create action except you need to accept and id, Read the entity from db, map it to the viewmodel. (Set the SelectedDept id property value as well) and send it to the view.

Comment: Hey thank you very much , thus mapping is right through the model and not the ViewBag , good response